# discord.py ClientConnectorError raise handling

Tags: python-3.x, exception, discord.py

I have the current code below:

```
try:
    client.run(token)
except:
    print("Connection error!")
```

There is one issue with this, a bare 'Except' is not a good idea. How do I type something like "Except ClientConnectorError:"?

Specific raise:

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:default [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that you need to import the aiohttp module and use the class from there:

```
from aiohttp import connector

try:
    client.run(token)
except connector.ClientConnectorError:
    pass
```

You can of course do other actions instead of `pass`.